# Does Blender Have a Cycle Select Option?

Tags: edit-mode, select

Sometimes you have two edges that are directly on top of each other, which makes it almost impossible to select the one you want.  Does Blender have an option to cycle through the possible edges/faces/etc you are trying to select?
So far the only option I know of is hiding the one so you can select the other, but a cycling method would be way more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It helps to be in *X-Ray* mode, but this is not necessary.  Simply do not move the mouse and click again.  One way to enter X-Ray mode is to use the toggle in the header. It's the icon that looks like overlapped rectangles:

[image: how to toggle X-Ray mode]

This does not work on edges that are not apparently close enough together.  There you simply have to zoom in.

Comment: thanks man!  X-Ray mode is helpful alright.